# submit form data to custom page for emailing

Tags: shopify, liquid

I created a custom form on a shopify page and when the submit button is pressed i want all the data within the form fields to go to another page that is a request form where the user would enter data and upon submission the data will be emailed instead of buying anything. How is this done in shopify? the page that i'm talking about is this one

https://pharaohmfg.com/collections/billiard-pool-tables/products/luxor-pool-table

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to another page with a custom form but the email will not be send since you are required to use `/contact#contact_form` as the form action.

One way to bypass that is to submit the form as a contact form and redirect the user upon form success. Please note that this way if you submit the form more than once you will get a google challenge for spam protection which is not user friendly.

Another way is to create a custom APP and using a proxy to submit to that page and handle the request from there.

Or an another option is to use a third party app of some sort and use their form builder ( hopefully allowing you to tie the product variants in some way to the actual form ).

There are free services like `formspree` that allows direct submissions to an email but I don't know what are the limits there.

Comment: What about creating the form, then copy the html of the form, remove the form in shopify and add an html block where you paste in the form and then in that same block you change the form action to something else?